# Try to use the getJSON function but it's not returning anything

Tags: javascript, php

This is my getJSON:

```
$(function () {
    var neededData;
    $.getJSON('/ajax/connected-devices-data.php', function(jsonData) {
        neededData = jsonData;
        console.log(neededData);
    }); 
});
```

And this is my php:

```
use NET2GRID\Data\CurrentlyConnectedDevices;

require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$cd = new CurrentlyConnectedDevices();
$data = $cd->getConnectedDevicesFromDatabase();

print json_encode($data);
```

When I look at my site where I run this the console remains empty but according to what I'm used to there should be a json object there.

This is the jsonresponse I get from the php code when I run it individually:

> {"SUCCESS":[[1493642582000,912],[1493718591000,909]],"PING_NOT_RECEIVED":[[1493642582000,631],[1493718591000,635]],"TCP_CNX_FAILED":[[1493642582000,7],[1493718591000,7]]}

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Does your PHP file giving any JSON response when you are making a direct call to it?

Comment: run php file directly on browser and check the response of `print json_encode($data);` is it printing anything or showing blank?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart yes there is a response in json

Comment: @mi6crazyheart added that response to the question

Comment: @Wouter  when you are running your script code file at that time check your browser console and see is there any error?

Comment: @AlivetoDie no errors

Comment: @Wouter  your code worked for me. definitely   you have error somewhere in console or in php file. did you shown all code of your php file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143174/discussion-between-wouter-and-alive-to-die).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following AJAX code..

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/connected-devices-data.php"     
}).done(function( response ) {
    alert( "Response received: " + response );
});
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

Above code was not the solution of the question asked. It was the error on the **web server which has not configured properly with PHP**.

Comment: If in response you are getting whole PHP code then there might have some error in your web server. Maybe web server is not configured with PHP properly.

Comment: The web server was indeed not configured properly but I'll accept your answer as it seems to help. Add to the answer about the web server and it will be better

Comment: @Wouter Glad to know your problem has fixed. I've updated the reply answer with the actual issue.